# Has the sign of the son of man been revealed?

Tags: matthew, olivet-discourse, apocalyptic, son-of-man

The sign has been seen by all, but without revelation it is not attributed to the son of man by those who see His sign.  What is the sign of the son of man?

> Matt 24:30 - "Then will appear the **sign of the Son of Man in
> heaven**. And then all the peoples of the earth will mourn when they
> see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and
> great glory.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for this question. However, if you are wanting a hermeneutical answer, it would help if you gave us more of a clue as to why you have tagged this with 'revelation' and 'apocalyptic'. Do you have particular verses in either the book of Revelation, or of Jesus' own prophetic words? Given your own answer, I also have to ask if it's worth while anybody answering who has a different point of view? As this is not a chat site, I won't go into this more. One question that is asked is not to be a launch-pad for further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome Anne. The origin of this revelation is not from scripture but rather a direct revelation from the LORD Yeshua. The truth of this revelation is supported throughout scripture from the fire called down by Jeremiah to the LORD’s description of his return in Matthew 24:27. I did this question and answer style to share the revelations I’ve been instructed to share.

Comment: Out of courtesy to your readers I think it would be helpful if you told us what text you are referring to by quoting it and citing the version you are using.

Comment: @JeremySt.Germain Claims of direct revelation from God cannot be supported on this site, because none of us have any way to validate them. All questions must also quote the verse they ask about. It was nice of Dottard to help edit your question, but please include the verse(s) yourself next time.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the group.

This was a very general question, so I thought a simple answer referring to the scriptures that use the phrase "Son of Man" and which combine "sign" and "son of Man might be helpful.

In Daniel 7:11 we read: "I saw in the night visions, and behold, with the clouds of heaven there came one like a **son of man**, and he came to the Ancient of Days and was presented before him. (ESV)

And we see Jesus use this imagery when He says in Matthew 24:30 "Then will appear in heaven **the sign of the Son of Man**, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and *they will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven* with power and great glory. (ESV)

Again we see in Matthew 26:64 Jesus said to him, "You have said so. But I tell you, from now on *you will see the **Son of Man** seated at the right hand of Power and coming on the clouds of heaven*." (ESV)  Then, in Matt. 26:65 the High priest tears his robes (which is actually a violation of the Levitical law) he declares "He has uttered blasphemy. What further witnesses do we need? You have now heard his blasphemy." (ESV)  (It appears that the priest at least understood that Jesus was appropriating the sign of the Messiah's return in Daniel.)

This also lines-up with the prophecy of the angels who accompany the disciples at the ascension of Christ in Acts 1:9-11. After Jesus "was lifted up, and a cloud took him out of their sight.  And while they were gazing into heaven as he went, behold, two men stood by them in white robes, and said, 'Men of Galilee, why do you stand looking into heaven? This Jesus, who was taken up from you into heaven, will come in the same way as you saw him go into heaven.' "(ESV)

For these reasons, I believe that the **sign of the Son of Man** is the appearance of Jesus, the Messiah, returning to the Earth, for all to see.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence in the text of Matt 24:9-31 is clear:

**Tribulation** consisting of

- V9, Persecution
- V10, betrayal
- V11 false prophets
- V12 - multiplication of wickedness

**Abomination of Desolation**

- V15, at the sight of the Abomination of Desolation predicted by the prophet Daniel 9:27, 11:31, 12:11, people should flee to the mountains
- V19, great misery

**Heavenly signs** after the tribulation

- V29, Sun darkened
- Moon does not give its light
- Stars fall from sky
- powers of heaven shaken

**Sign of the Son of Man**

- V30, Sign of the Son of Man appears in Heaven (Dan 7:13, 14) = sight of the son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven
- V31 - angels sent out to gather the elect